# Is it okay to use std::this_thread* functions from boost::threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, std

Is it okay to mix and match things from `boost::thread` and `std::thread`, or should one set of functions be used for each?

I ask because my code uses `boost::thread`s, but I've found that `boost::this_thread::sleep_for` doesn't behave properly when setting the system time back, but `std::this_thread::sleep_for` does, so I'd like to change my sleep function call and avoid changing all my `boost::thread`s to `std::thread`s if possible.

Comment: Mixing them will clearly give undefined behavior. It might work if your standard library happens to use code enough like Boost's, but I'd rate the likelihood as fairly low (though it's impossible to really even give an educated guess when you don't tell us what compiler/library you're using).

Comment: Just an fyi, boost 1.58 fixes the sleep bug you are talking about (released today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice you might get away with things iff/because the implementations use the same implementations (e.g. `pthread` on linux).

However, you *will* be breaking invariants. Simple example: Boost Thread's interruption points won't function with non-boost synchronisation primitives (including `std::this_thread::sleep_*`).

Therefore I'd avice against actually *mixing* libraries for controlling related threads, lest you want to risk running into suprises ¹

Of course, if libraries have completely separate concerns (e.g. they use threads internally, "in the black box"), there should be no issue combining those libraries in one process.

---

¹ I can see deadlocks happening, and data races/leaks do not require a huge stretch of imagination (think thread local data support/call_once/`set_value_at_thread_exit`...)

Answer (score 0):

It is inadvisable to mix APIs within one thread.  As @Jerry Coffin mentions, you may well run into undefined behaviour. There may be thread local state that these APIs rely upon that would not be compatible with threads created by a different API.

However, it should be fine to use `std::thread` and `boost::thread` separately within the one process.  Since @Red Alert says 1.58 fixes the bug, this should solve your problem. Otherwise, you can temporarily revert to `usleep()` and similar functions with `#ifdef`s for different platforms.

Comment: I think `usleep` would still break library invariants; The upside would be that it makes this clearer. E.g. few people will expect interruption points to magically work with `usleep`